# Ed25519 threshold signature verification without knowing the single personal public keys

Tags: signature, ed25519, threshold-cryptography

I read about ways to create a t-of-n threshold signature, corresponding to a collective public key of n players. (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ford-cfrg-cosi-00 and [Does Ed25519 support cryptographic threshold signatures?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20581/does-ed25519-support-cryptographic-threshold-signatures)).

Is it possible to verify a t-of-n signature, by knowing only the collective public key of all n players, and not the personal public keys of the signing (t) players? I.e. the signature can be treated (verified) like a "normal" Ed25519 signature?

Comment: So essentially you are asking "is there a secure threshold multi-party signing protocol that generates signatures verifiable using the standard Ed25519 verification algorithm"?

Comment: The answer is yes.